# how to put int type array in string type arrayadapter?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

or how do I insert images alongside with quotes? my idea is create an int array filled with `R.drawable.image` it doesnt work since the arrayadapter type is string. 
here's the code:

TitleListActivity.java

```
package course.examples.quoteviewer;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TitlesListActivity extends ListActivity {

public static String[] mTitleArray;
public static String[] mQuoteArray;

public static final String INDEX = "index";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mTitleArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Titles);
    mQuoteArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Quotes);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TitlesListActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_text_item_layout, TitlesListActivity.mTitleArray));
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    Intent showItemIntent = new Intent(TitlesListActivity.this,
            QuoteListActivity.class);
    showItemIntent.putExtra(INDEX, mQuoteArray[pos]);
    startActivity(showItemIntent);
}

}
```

QutoeListActivity.java

```
package course.examples.quoteviewer;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class QuoteListActivity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String quote = intent.getStringExtra(TitlesListActivity.INDEX);

    if (null != quote) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(QuoteListActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_text_item_layout, new String[] { quote }));
    }
}
}
```

list_text_item_layout.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textSize="32sp" >
</TextView>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">FragmentQuoteViewerWithActivity</string>
<string-array name="Titles">
    <item>The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark</item>
    <item>King Lear</item>
    <item>Julius Caesar</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="Quotes">
    <item>Now cracks a noble heart. Good-night, sweet prince; And flights of angels sing thee   to thy rest.</item>
    <item>As flies to wanton boys, are we to the gods; they kill us for their sport.</item>
    <item>There is a tide in the affairs of men, which taken at the flood, leads on to fortune.  Omitted, all the voyage of their life is bound in shallows and in miseries.</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your probably want to create your own `ArrayAdapter` that is typed to a simple class that holds an image resource (`int`) and your quote (`String`).

```
public class QuoteListAdapter extends ArrayAdapater<QuotedImage> {
    // check link for examples
}

static class QuotedImage {
    int imageResource;
    String quote;
}
```

Check [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond the capabilities of the built-in ArrayAdapter, I'm afraid. You'll need to create a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter and takes both Strings and ints. It doesn't have to extend ArrayAdapter, but that makes things easier.

In your custom adapter, the getView() method should inflate a custom layout XML file for each list item, and this layout file will contain views to display both the image and the quote. This is where you'll populate both the ImageView and the TextView with the data you passed to the adapter.

Vogella has an incredible resource for writing a custom list adapter, here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html